# Limit on number of features in Cox Proportional Hazards model with penalized spline

Tags: survival, cox-model, curve-fitting, splines, proportional-hazards

I am trying to fit a Cox proportional hazards model with penalized splines using the `survival` R package with the following, but it seems like I am hitting a limit on the number of coefficients that can be estimated given the total number of observations in the dataset.

For example,

```
library(survival)

data(lung)
lung <- na.omit(lung)
lung <- data.frame(apply(lung, 2, as.numeric))
nrow(lung) # 167 rows
model <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ pspline(inst) + pspline(age) 
               + pspline(ph.ecog) + pspline(ph.karno) + pspline(pat.karno)
               + pspline(meal.cal) + pspline(wt.loss) + sex, data=lung,
               method='breslow')
```

This yields `Error in coxpenal.fit(X, Y, istrat, offset, init = init, control, weights = weights,  : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 5)`.

But when I double the number of observations:

```
lung.2x <- as.data.frame(lapply(lung, rep, 2))
nrow(lung.2x) # 334 rows
model.2x <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ pspline(inst) + pspline(age)
                  + pspline(ph.ecog) + pspline(ph.karno) + pspline(pat.karno)
                  + pspline(meal.cal) + pspline(wt.loss) + sex, data=lung.2x,
                  method='breslow')
```

This runs.

Could anyone provide some insight as to why the model won't fit on the smaller dataset? Looking at `model.2x$coefficients`, I see that there are 85 coefficients estimated which is still fewer than the number of observations in the smaller dataset.

(If it helps - the default values for `pspline()` are 4 degrees of freedom and degree = 3, i.e. a cubic spline.)

Comment: It’s the number of events, not the number of total cases, that matters for these considerations in Cox regression. Even if a fit is possible with a low event/predictor ratio, once you start getting down toward a 10/1 ratio you are at risk of overfitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to apply splines to predictors that aren't continuous variables, while not recognizing that one of those variables had only a limited number of distinct values.

In the `lung` data "inst" is an institution code that should be treated as an unordered 17-level factor or, better, as a random effect; "ph.ecog" is a potentially 5-level ordered performance score that only takes on 4 levels in your complete-cases subset.

I have no problem with fitting the model when those 2 predictors are handled appropriately: `frailty(inst)` to treat institutions as a random effect, and `ordered(ph.ecog)` to use ECOG score as an ordered categorical predictor. The model:

```
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ frailty(inst) + pspline(age) + 
    ordered(ph.ecog) + pspline(ph.karno) + pspline(pat.karno) + 
    pspline(meal.cal) + pspline(wt.loss) + sex, data = lung, 
    method = "breslow")
```

is probably terribly overfit with only 120 events, but there is no convergence problem.

Your convergence problem seems to have stemmed from the "ph.ecog" predictor. It only has 4 levels in your complete-cases subset, and the default for `pspline()`is thus too many at 4 df. Taking your original model and just changing the corresponding term to `pspline(ph.ecog,2)` led to no technical difficulty.